# Cryptic message from Google Developer console

Tags: android, google-play

I have an app and I'm uploading a new release. As soon as I publish the APK the Google developer console complains about this:

[image]

I have no idea what they are talking about:

> Your app currently targets API level 25 and must target at least API level 26

Why the yellow warning? They are saying my app should target at least API level 26. My app is targeting API level 25 so it should be fine. From my point of view "at least 26" means 26 and below. I don't understand

Comment: I would click on the blue "learn how"... (My understanding of at least is 26 and above)

Comment: @RolandStarke I get that, but the "minimum API level" can be a lot lower than that. There is the thing called "target level" and the "minimum level". That's why I don't get the warning

Comment: It refers to minimum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"At least 26" does not mean 26 and below. It means 26 and above.

The [definition in the Cambridge English dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/at-least) "as much as, or more than, a number or amount"

Note that this is talking about minimum *target* SDK (`targetSdkVersion`), not minimum SDK (`minSdkVersion`) ([docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element)). So this is not saying that every developer has to *only* support Oreo - that would be `minSdkVersion`. It is saying that every App has to have `targetSdkVersion` >= 26, ie be compatible with Oreo. [See the blog post](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/12/improving-app-security-and-performance.html) for more details.

Comment: I understand english but it cannot be it. It's like saying that starting from August 2018 Google will not accept anymore apps with API level below 26. I mean, everyone should update to Android Oreo? 95% of the app out there will be obsolete and they will not work anymore? I don't think so

Comment: Clarified my answer to explain the difference between minimum target SDK and minSdkVersion - hopefully it helps.